# EEPROM restoring doesn't work

Tags: c++, arduino

I am working on a DIY project with Arduinos (Nano board). I have problems with Serial communication between the first and second Arduinos. The first Arduino sends one character (the letter r) to the 2nd, and that's how the second Arduino starts restoring bytes from EEPROM (bytes from 0-25). The only problem is, the second Arduino doesn't send bytes correctly, or maybe the first Arduino doesn't store them correctly.

The second Arduino has default values in EEPROM:

```
EEPROMWritelong(EEPROM_DISTANCE, 1500);
EEPROMWritelong(EEPROM_DISTANCE_B, 100);
EEPROMWritelong(EEPROM_DISTANCE_C, 1000);
EEPROMWritelong(EEPROM_DISTANCE_D, 400); 
EEPROM.write(EEPROM_MAX_SPEED, 43);
EEPROM.write(EEPROM_TOP_SPEED, 38);
EEPROMWritelong(EEPROM_TRIP_TIME, 1800);
EEPROMWritelong(EEPROM_WOKR_HOURS, 3600);
```

Loop function in the second Arduino:

```
if (Serial.available()) {
  incoming = Serial.read();
  if (incoming == 'r') {
    uint8_t address = 0;
    notSend = 255;
    do {
      Serial.write(EEPROM.read(address));
      address++;
      delay(50);
    }
    while (address < 26);
      notSend = 0;
    }
  }
```

Code to restore bytes on the first Arduino:

```
uint8_t byteCount = 0;
Serial.write('r'); // STARTS RESTORING
do {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    if (byteCount >= 0 && byteCount <= 17) EEPROM.write(byteCount, Serial.read());
    // FROM DISTANCE TO TOP SPEED (BYTES 0 - 17)
    else if (byteCount >= 18 && byteCount <= 21) EEPROM.write(byteCount + 8, Serial.read());
    // TRIP TIME
    else EEPROM.write(byteCount + 16, Serial.read());
    // WORK HOURS
    byteCount++;
  }
}
while (byteCount != 26);
```

I did print of all bytes during this process, and bytes don't match at all.
The left side is sending bytes from the second Arduino to the first, the right side is receiving bytes on the first Arduino from the second Arduino.

[image: Serial monitor]

Comment: Off topic: You can exterminate a lot of duplicated code by making and using a function to handle the endian swap.

Comment: @user4581301 You see something I don't?

Comment: I think I see what You mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the writes are not working.  Each `EEPROM.write()` statement, per [the documentation here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMWrite), takes 3.3 milliseconds to complete.  I don't see anything in your code that allows for proper pacing of the writes other than the time to check `Serial.available()`.

Also be aware that all AVR chips' EEPROMs support unlimited reads, but have a write endurance of only about 100,000 cycles.  So you should be judicious in how often you write to EEPROM.  Ideally this is for persistent settings and values can are often read and seldom written.  Put a bunch of EEPROM writes in a fast loop and you could exceed the endurance of the EEPROM very quickly.  Then the EEPROM is ruined and you need a new chip (and bootloader) or a new Arduino.  I know this from bad experience.  ;)

Comment: So I should use delay?

Comment: To ensure that writes are effective you're going to need some kind of delay, yes.  Notice how the documentation I referred you to has a delay in the very last line?  You need some delay to insure effective writes.

Comment: I tried delays between 5ms and 250ms. Only one time was good communation.

Comment: @SilvioCro well 5ms should be adequate.  Why don't you re-post your code in your question so that we can see if other problems are apparent?  I jumped on the EEPROM delay because I've burned up a few EEPROMs in my experience.  ;)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Yes, EEPROM writes are slow, but last time I checked the necessary delays were already took care of by the library call. You can see in the example that all the 256 bytes of EEPROM are written in a tight loop, without any explicit delay.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Where is a problem then? I mean, one time writes were good, after few seconds I started restore again, and writes were wrong. I really don't Know what could be the problem.